# c# PInvoke w_char_t**

Tags: interop, pinvoke

I have the following c++ function which I cannot alter (3rd-Party):

[c++]

```
int __stdcall TEST(wchar_t **xml, int &result_size)
{
  // xml is instantiated here!
}
```

[c#]

```
class native
{
   [DllImport("somedll.dll")]

   public static extern int TEST(StringBuilder a, ref int size);
   {
   }
}
```

Example:

```
 StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
 int size = 0;
 native.Test(b,ref size)
```

The stringbuilder object only contains first character . If I resize the object:
   b.Length = size; The data is incorrect except first character.

Is this the correct way to pass wchar_t** from c++ to c#?

Regards,

John

Comment: This function is hard to call reliably from native code, the caller has to release the memory for the string buffer.  That doesn't get any better when you have to pinvoke it, you can't release it.  That you get the first char is remarkable, that indicates that the actual function argument is wchar_t*, not wchar_t**.  In which case you're okay but you'll have to use CharSet.Unicode in the pinvoke declaration.

Comment: I think that was a coincidence. I can no longer reproduce that result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function would be p/invoked like this:

```
[DllImport(@"mylib.dll")]
static extern int TEST(out IntPtr xml);
```

I removed the size paramter since it is not needed since you can use a null-terminated string.

Call the function like this:

```
IntPtr xmlptr;
int retval = TEST(out xmlptr);
string xml = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(xmlptr);
// deallocate xmlptr somehow
```

The tricky bit is to deallocate the memory allocated on the native side. Either use a shared allocator, e.g. the COM allocator. Or export a deallocator from the native code.

Personally I'd re-design the interface to use COM BSTR. I'd have the C++ return a BSTR and on the managed side use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]. Then the framework handles all the deallocation and marshalling for you.

Comment: @John You've gone quiet. Are you still interested in this question?

Comment: So sorry for the delay. I wrapped the function in a c++ dll and simplified the signiture to be more c# friendly.